# Assassin's Creed: Revelation DLC (The Lost Archive)

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I am going back to my old games and filling the gaps of missing DLCs but as of today AC:Revelation's The Lost Archives DLC is no longer available on Uplay nor anywhere outside of it.

The only way I have found out is to get the AC:Revelations - Ottoman Edition which includes this DLCs.

Therefore my question is: **Would buying the Ottoman Edition and then using its activation key in Uplay "upgrade" my standard AC:Revelations version to Ottoman Edition? Hence giving me access to The Lost Archives?
If not, is there any other way to get this DLC today?**

Thanks a lot for any response, this is very vital to me

Comment: Note: The Lost Archives is essentially 7 Desmond missions and a freerunning puzzle dungeon with a sword at the end. If you didn't like the Desmond missions, you might want to skip this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a reddit thread at https://www.reddit.com/r/assassinscreed/comments/258ltk/where_can_i_buy_the_lost_archive/chesuy8, you might be able to buy this through Steam and get a DLC unlock key for Uplay. If it doesn't work, you should be able to get the purchase refunded.

Alternatively, you can buy the DLC on Amazon at [https://www.amazon.com/Assassins-Creed-Revelations-Archive-Download/dp/B007CMQI3C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007CMQI3C), which also gives a UPlay Key according to the Q&A on the article.